# Unique key across tables

Tags: sql, hash, unique

[image]

I have the table schema as above in the picture and now I have the requirement that the combination of `permission_key` and the (key, value) pairs for that permission_value is unique, meaning there can't not be two values, e.g.

1. `id => 1, permission_key => "test"` with permission_keys `key => "test", value => "thisisatest"`

then there can't be another one

2. `id => 2, permission_key => "test"` with permission_keys `key => "test", value => "thisisatest"`

but there can be another value, e.g.

3. `id => 2, permission_key => "test"` with permission_keys `key => "test", value => "thisisnowanothertest"`

**Important**
Another permission_key is allowed to have the same key-value pair then, e.g.

4. `id => 3, permission_key => "another"` with permission_keys `key => "test", value => "thisisatest"`

is allowed.

I thought of making a hash of `permission_key` and each `key => value` pair of the keys to enforce uniqueness, but therefore I need a suitable hash function.

It is only that there are no multiple permission_value's with the same key-value pair.

If that is not possible, I thought about using mongodb, I think compound unique indexes might be suitable for this then?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want a unique constraint.  I think this is what you are describing:

```
alter table permission_keys add constraint unq_permision_keys_2
    unique (key, value)
```

Comment: No, because then I could create two entries in with same permission_key but different id, with same key-value pairs.

Comment: Then leave out the `id`.

Comment: Yes, but then I could not have the same key-value pair on another permission_key